# What does the "Fabric.framework/run" build phase actually do?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, crashlytics

I use the [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com/) framework for crash collecting in iOS Apps.

When you use the framework, a "Build Phase" is added to your target that runs `/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run <big-hex-blob> <another-even-biger-hex-blob>`.

I'd love to know that these actually do – I'm not entirely happy with having external vendors' tools monkey about with my build, I'm old school like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

The run script build phase is used, along with your `<APIkey> and <BuildSecret>`, to automatically handle the uploading of dSYMs so that you, and other developers, never need to manually upload one.

Similarly, the `/Crashlytics.framework/submit` command is used for distributions through Beta, our beta distribution service.

Comment: That seems like a pretty sound use-case. I'll get over my old-shool-ness! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just to add, since there's no documentation about the `run` script: you need to `run` at least once in order to add a new app to Fabric. We migrated our build scripts to use the individual `submit` and `upload-symbols` scripts for existing apps, but discovered that new apps weren't being added to Fabric, even though uploads were successful.

Turns out the `run` script is doing something other than uploading dSYMs, as it's required to fully register the app so that it'll be visible in Fabric/Crashlytics.

Comment: Great point and spot on that it is used for activating apps in Fabric as well.